# Want to output ID value of user and display it on console

Tags: node.js, mapping, sails.js, waterline, onesignal

I am using a sailsjs framework for an app. I am building, and I am trying to extract the id value from a model I have:

```
const memoryCreatorId = _(Memory.creator).map('id').value();
console.log(memoryCreatorId);
   const message = {
        app_id: '***********************',
        contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
        filters: [{"field": "tag", "key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": memoryCreatorId}],
        ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
        ios_badgeCount: 1
      };
    return PushNotificationService.sendNotification(message);
```

I'm basically trying to get what would be the Memory.creator.User.id value. So basically the userid of the person who creates a memory. I'm trying to get it from the "Memory" model "creator" attribute, which maps to the "User" model, and from the "User" model, extract the "id" attribute. Thanks for your help in advance!

Memory model below:

```
Memory.js
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    creator: {
      model: 'User'
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    description: {
      type: 'text'
    },
    contentUrl: {
      type: 'string',
      url: true
    },
    cropRect: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    likers: {
      collection: 'User',
      via: 'memoryLikes'
    },
    comments: {
      collection: 'Comment',
      via: 'memory'
    },
    update: {
      model: 'Update',
    },
    cause: {
      model: 'Cause',
    }
  }
};
```

User model is a follows:

```
User.js
'use strict';

const uuid = require('node-uuid');

const CipherService = require('../services/CipherService');
const BraintreeService = require('../services/BraintreeService');

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultsTo: () => uuid.v4(),
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      uuidv4: true
    },
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      email: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    passwordResetToken: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    passwordResetTokenExpires: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['admin', 'member']
    },
    city: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    state: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    address: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    institution: {
      model: 'Institution'
    },
    major: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    contentUrl: {
      type: 'string',
      url: true,
      defaultsTo: AwsService.getAssetImageUrl('user-default.png')
    },
    cropRect: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    graduationYear: {
      type: 'integer'
    },
    donations: {
      collection: 'Donation',
      via: 'donor'
    },
    memories: {
      collection: 'Memory',
      via: 'creator'
    },
    causes: {
      collection: 'Cause',
      via: 'followers',
      dominant: true
    },
    adminCauses: {
      collection: 'Cause',
      via: 'admins'
    },
    isLeader: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    isCurrentStudent: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    adminTitle: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    paymentProfile: {
      model: 'PaymentProfile'
    },
    jsonWebTokens: {
      collection: 'Jwt',
      via: 'owner'
    },
    memoryLikes: {
      collection: 'Memory',
      via: 'likers'
    },
    updateLikes: {
      collection: 'Update',
      via: 'likers'
    },
    toJSON: function() {
      return User.clean(this);
    }
  },
  beforeUpdate: (values, next) => {
    CipherService.hashPassword(values).then(() => next()).catch(next);
  },
  beforeCreate: (values, next) => {
    CipherService.hashPassword(values).then(() => next()).catch(next);
  },
  clean: (user) => {
    //let obj = user.toObject();

    delete user.password;
    delete user.jsonWebTokens;
    delete user.passwordResetToken;
    delete user.passwordResetTokenExpires;

    return user;
  }
};
```

Comment: not sure what you want to do to be honest. If you have instance of model (got from Model.find()) you can just use instance.id . I am really confused about your question.

Comment: I'm basically trying to get what would be the Memory.creator.User.id value. So basically the userid of the person who creates a memory. I'm trying to get it from the "Memory" model "creator" attribute, which maps to the "User" model, and from the "User" model extract the "id" attribute.